# angular ngx-bootstrap onClick on alert module

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstap alert module to show alerts. When someone clicks on account number in the alert, I want to show modal with further details of the account. I did not find onClick event on the alert module. There are events handlers for close events but nothing on click events.

I tried to use innerHTML to include the code to create onClick like functionality but it's not working.

Here is the html part -

```
<div *ngFor="let alert of alerts">
          <alert [type]="alert.type" [dismissible]="dismissible">
              <span [innerHTML]="alert.msg | safe: 'html'"></span>
            </alert>
</div>
```

I have defined Safe pipe which is working fine.

Here is the return values for alerts -

```
[{
            "type": "success",
            "msg": "Adjustments - Marry Jonson <a href='javascript:folioClicked(1305879);'>#130-5879</a> Amount $102."
        }]
```

I have folioClicked() function defined in component. However, I don't know how to call it. I tried calling with javascript:folioClicked but that is not working and giving error "Uncaught ReferenceError: folioClicked is not defined
    at :1:1".

It seems that it is trying to find the code in javascript. I can understand the reason for that. However, not able to find a way to call component function through innerHTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a click event inside an alert in this way. I hope it will help you.

```
<alert type="success">
 <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
  <a (click)="fooClick(accNo)">Account.no. {{accNo}}</a>
</alert>
```

[Here I am adding running snippet link to help you it.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-bootstrap-alert-izukau)